# How to load UIView in Portrait mode irrespective of device orientation - IOS 6

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, uiview

I am working on iOS 6 application, I have handled the UIview rotation using following methods...

```
-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations

{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}


- (BOOL) shouldAutorotate {
    return YES;
}
```

Everything is working fine, problem is initial view loading is decided based on device orientation, for e.g.: if I keep my device in landscape mode even though I have returned as forcibly portrait in supportedInterfaceOrientations view is showing in landscape only, once device is rotated to portrait after that it is not going to landscape mode, all working fine. Is it possible to load a View at certain mode irrespective of the device orientation?

I have googled and nothing worked.

NOTE: I am using navigation controller. And I have added category for UINavigationController.

// Custom categoy to handle orientation in IOS6

```
@implementation UINavigationController (Rotation_IOS6)

-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return [[self.viewControllers lastObject] shouldAutorotate];
}

-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return [[self.viewControllers lastObject] supportedInterfaceOrientations];
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
{
    return [[self.viewControllers lastObject] preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation];
}
@end
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use this method:

```
 - (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
{
  return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
```

Add this method  along with `category` for `UINavigationController` in `appDelegate`.

```
- (NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window
{
  UINavigationController *navigationController = (UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController;
  //check for which controller u need these methods
  if([navigationController.visibleViewController isKindOfClass:[yourViewController class]]) //provide specific view controller where u want protrait
  {
    [navigationController shouldAutorotate];
    [navigationController supportedInterfaceOrientations];
    [navigationController preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation];
  }
  return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
}
```

**Note** : remove from all viewController if u have added `category` for `UINavigationController`. It should be only in appDelegate.

Comment: hi prince.. Yesterday problem was with iPad mini's button, once I switch it works fine... :). Today's question: where should I add this, I have tried in corresponding views before.. It didn't worked.

Comment: In controller function is not getting called.

Comment: I have added it in category, there also preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation in not got hit while loading initially.

Comment: - (NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window this function is getting called multiple times for me whenever it is called  category method also called, again coming back to same function...leads to finally hanging and crash, category is in app delegate.mm only

Comment: Please check the edit I have given the category how I am using

Comment: Check edited answer as i have changed supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow

Comment: After changes function got called, but the view is still loading with respect to previous view.